# vector does not erase content correctly (infite amount run of copy asignment operator untill crash [BEX])?

Tags: c++, vector, structure, destruction, rule-of-three

Well my problem is that after I want to "unload" loaded DLL's the copy assignmnent operator is called an unlimited amount of times until crash.

The code from which I remove the vector data looks like this:

```
void UnloadPlugins()
{
    dbg(("[DBG]UnloadPlugins()"));
    for(std::vector<DLLInfo>::iterator it = plugins.begin(); it != plugins.end(); ++it) 
    {
        plugins.erase(it);
    }
    dbg(("[DBG]UnloadPlugins()::Done"));
}
```

however "[DBG]UnloadPlugins()::Done" gets never printed.

this is my copy assignmnent operator:

```
// 2. copy assignment operator
DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)
{
    dbg(("[DBG]Start-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)"));
    Instance = that.Instance;//hinstance
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 1"));
    //Identifier.assign(that.Identifier);//string
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 2"));
    IsAMX = that.IsAMX;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 3"));
    dwSupportFlags = that.dwSupportFlags;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 4"));
    Load = that.Load;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 5"));
    Unload = that.Unload;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 6"));
    Supports = that.Supports;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 7"));
    ProcessTick = that.ProcessTick;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 8"));
    AmxLoad = that.AmxLoad;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 9"));
    AmxUnload = that.AmxUnload;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 10"));
    UseDestructor = that.UseDestructor;//bool
    dbg(("[DBG]DLLInfo 11"));
    KeyboardHit = that.KeyboardHit;//integer
    dbg(("[DBG]End-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)"));
    return *this;
}
```

So the log looks like:

```
[17:50:50] [DBG]UnloadPlugins()
[17:50:50] [DBG]~DLLInfo    
[17:50:50] [DBG]~DLLInfo::if(this->UseDestructor) passed    
[17:50:50] [DBG]~DLLInfo::if(this->UseDestructor)::if(this->Unload != NULL && this->IsAMX) passed    
[17:50:50] [DBG]~DLLInfo::end    
[17:50:50] [DBG]Start-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 1   
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 2    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 3    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 4    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 5    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 6    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 7    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 8    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 9    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 10    
[17:50:50] [DBG]DLLInfo 11    
[17:50:50] [DBG]End-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)    
[17:50:50] [DBG]Start-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)    
...  
[17:50:50] [DBG]End-DLLInfo& operator=(const DLLInfo& that)
...repeat until crash
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`erase` returns an iterator (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)), instead of `++it` in your for, you should try `it = plugins.erase(it);`

But seeing your code, if you only `erase` everything, you'd be better off calling `clear` (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/))